# When trying to define a union I receive the following error: GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "["

Tags: graphql, schema, apollo-client, apollo-server, unions

I am trying to use Apollo Client and Apollo Server to query a third party API where the data sometimes comes in the form of a single object and sometimes comes in the form of an array of objects. I'm trying to define a union in my typeDefs gql string in order to account for the data variability, but everytime I do, I receive `GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "[".`. I've removed most of the schema, as it is quite long. I'm assuming I can't define a union in this way, but for the life of me can't find any explanations on another way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server");

module.exports = gql`
    type Query {
        getPropertyDetails(zpid: String): [PropertyDetails]
        getPropertiesOverview: [PropertyOverview]
    }
union RoomOrRooms = Room | [Rooms]

type Room {
        level: String
        dimensions: String
        features: String
        roomFeatures: [String]
        roomArea: String
        roomAreaSource: String
        roomLength: String
        width: String
        roomDescription: String
        roomWidth: String
        roomLevel: String
        roomLengthWidthUnits: String
        roomLengthWidthSource: String
        roomDimensions: String
        roomAreaUnits: String
        roomType: String
        length: String
        description: String
        area: String
    }

type ResoFacts {
        rooms: RoomOrRooms
    }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can union a type and an array of a type, just two individual types.

But you're making your life complicated. Just have your API *always* return an array of rooms. If the API brings back a single room, just make it into an array of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

The [provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74986693/652728) is correct that you can't use an array as part of a union, and I also agree that you probably should just always provide an array when it's a single one. There's not really a reason NOT to do it that way, and it'll be much much simpler to consume it that way.

That being said, if you really want to make it a single or multiple, you could do that with connections, like this:

```
type ReseverationRoomsConnection {
  nodes: [Room]
}

union RoomOrRooms = Room | ReservationRoomsConnection
```